# Ajax form won't display success message

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm having an issue with an contact form everything works except it will not show the success message after the form is added to the db.

The process script

```
$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post)
{
    include 'db.php';
    include 'functions.php';

    $name = stripslashes($_POST['name']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $phone = stripslashes($_POST['phone']);
    $device = stripslashes($_POST['device']);
    $model = stripslashes($_POST['model']);
    $subject = stripslashes($_POST['subject']);
    $message = stripslashes($_POST['message']);

    $error = '';

    // Check name

    if(!$name)
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter your name.<br />';
    }

    // Check email

    if(!$email)
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter an e-mail address.<br />';
    }

    if($email && !ValidateEmail($email))
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.<br />';
    }

    // Check phone number

    if(!$phone)
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter your phone number.<br />';
    }

    // Check device 

    if(!$device)
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter your device manufacturer.<br />';
    }

    // Check device model 

    if(!$model)
    {
        $error .= 'Please enter your device model.<br />';
    }

    // Check message (length)

    if(!$message || strlen($message) < 15)
    {
        $error .= "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.<br />";
    }

    // Get current time stampe
    $date = time();


    if(!$error)
    {

        $addDB = "INSERT INTO contactus (`name`,`email`,`phone`,`device`,`model`,`subject`,`message`, `date`, `read`) VALUES ('$name','$email','$phone','$device','$model','$subject','$message','$date', '')";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$addDB) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $sql - Error: ".mysqli_error(), E_USER_ERROR);

        echo 'OK';

    } else {

        echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';

    }

}
```

And here is the jQuery part

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                 
$(document).ready(function ()
{ // after loading the DOM
    $("#ajax-contacts").submit(function ()
    {
        // this points to our form
        var str = $(this).serialize(); // Serialize the data for the POST-request
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: 'includes/contact-process.php',
            data: str,
            success: function (msg)
            {
                $("#note").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings)
                {
                    if (msg == 'OK')
                    {
                        result = '<div class="notification_ok">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>';
                        $("#fields").hide();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = msg;
                    }
                    $(this).html(result);
                });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks any help is gladly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it adds the form into my database and instead of displaying the success messages and hiding the form it only shows OK

http://gyazo.com/0ee5ce344bfb2c050404e72565f9ba42

Comment: Ok, Here's the similar issue and a solution to your problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/21218261/1681154

And yes i think you don't need `$("#note").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings)`

Comment: Thanks for link i tried to add `print 'OK';` into my php script and it seems it still doesn't work  I've added `alert("Test");` and it seems that it doesn't get called in the `if (msg == 'OK')` and i still see OK above my form.

Answer (score 1):

Drop this line:

```
$("#note").ajaxComplete(function (event, request, settings)
```

You don't need it as you are already in the `success:` function.
For debugging purpose you can try to put in an `alert("Test");` just above that troublesome line to check if it is displayed.

Note that the `success` callbacks have been deprecated and you should instead use `.done`. See the [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info:

[image: jQuery API info]

You could also try and do some debugging yourself. E.g. Chrome has some really good developer tools where you can see a lot of stuff and you can even setup breakpoints and walk through your code step-by-step. Very useful.

- Hit `F12` to show Developer Tools.
- Go in to `Settings`:

[image: DevTools]

- Enable logging of XHR/Ajax requests:

[image: DevTools]

- When doing Ajax requests hereafter it will be logged in the `console`:

[image: DevTools]

Just rightclick on that Ajax request to trigger a new identical request. In this way you can see exactly what the browser sends and what your PHP script receives. Of course the request needs to be `GET` for you to debug the variables being passed.